# The Satan's rebellion in Rabbinic literature?

Tags: midrash, malach-angel, agada-stories-legends, satan

My understanding is that in most of Rabbinic literature, the Satan is viewed as simply the angel with the job of accusing mankind like in Iyov, and that the Christian notion of him as having rebelled against G-d and gotten kicked out of heaven is not present in Rabbinic writings. I am aware that there are older Jewish notions found in the Apocrypha and Dead Sea Scrolls that Christianity may have been drawing on, but that largely those traditions did not make it into mainstream Rabbinic thought.
However, I noticed that in Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer, there is a tradition that seems closer to the Christian understanding. Here, the term Palit (fugitive or one who was rescued) is applied to Michael because when the Satan and his supporters were forced out of heaven, the Satan attempted to grab Michael and drag him down as well, but G-d saved him and so he got this nickname.
Does anyone have any information about where this narrative might come from or if there are other sources like it elsewhere in Rabbinic Literature?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for the source for the Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer or similar such writings?

Comment: All of your  points assume that angels have free will, which the great majority of sources say that angels do not have free will, not even the Satan.  I think your question would be better if your cited the actual page of the Pirkei DeRebbe Eliezer.  I'm guessing that your source is tertiary and my be misstating what was actually written.

Comment: @BruceJames I'm so thrilled that you're back on the site! I have browsed your answers years after the fact (I started here in 2018) and have always found them quite useful.

Comment: @BruceJames - Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer is here - https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.27.2?vhe=Pirkei_Derabi_Eliezer&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @BruceJames Here is the source on Sefaria: https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.27.2 I would recommend you read it before guessing what it does or doesn't say, that way you can avoid reading into the text a predisposed interpretation.

Comment: Although closer to the Christian story, it doesn't say that the satan rebelled, only that he was removed from heaven, which can be understood to be unrelated to rebellion. That said,  grabbing Michael does seem to signify some sort of free will